# Split a div in 2 using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a rectangle with class `.box` and inside it, I have a button with class `.btn`. I need to make an effect in such a way that when I click on the button the rectangle should split in 2 from the center and one division should move to left and other division should move to the right. How do I do it using jquery or javascript? Or is there any way to do it without using jquery or javascript?

this is my HTML:

```
<div class="box">
<button class"btn"> click </button>
</div>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
.box{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:royalblue;
}
```

Comment: Try doing jquery clone and animate the divs

Comment: you want to duplicate the box so there's two of them?  Or somehow move half of it one way and half the other way?  Can you provide some before and after pictures of what you are looking for?

Comment: What should be shown beneath? ... I mean something that should be revealed? ... And what should happen with the button?

Comment: i just need half of my rectangle to move to left side and another half to move to right side on clicking the button. and on clicking button should disappear or let it stay there no worries..

Comment: is the rectangle just a colored box (that can be made up of two connecting halves originally)?  or is there some other content in there, other than the button?

Comment: @andi yes it can be like that.and if your about to post a comment just show me how to cut it with an angle i mean not at 90 degree any other degree..

Comment: @LGSon nothing needs to be reavealed..

Comment: you wouldn't be "cutting" a rectangle, at any angle.  you'd be creating something that looks like a rectangle, made up of the two pieces that you later want to separate.  see the other solutions below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach in jQuery starting with the `html` you presented in your question and then adding... a sprinkling of `.clone()`, a lot of `.css()` and a dash of `.animate()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('button').click(function() {
        $('.box button').remove();
        $('.box').clone().appendTo('.box').attr('class','halfbox left');
        $('.left').css({'position': 'absolute', 'display': 'block', 'top': '0', 'left': '0', 'width': '250px', 'height': '500px', 'backgroundColor': 'royalblue'});
        $('.left').clone().appendTo('.box').attr('class','halfbox right');
        $('.right').css({'left': 'auto', 'right': '0'});
        $('.box').css('backgroundColor', 'transparent');
        $('.left').animate({left: '-300px'}, 800);
        $('.right').animate({right: '-300px'}, 800);
    });

});
```

```css
.box {
position: relative;
display: block;
margin: 24px auto;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
background-color: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
<button type="button"> click </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot split HTML element. However, you can add other elements to it, if all you want to achieve is some visual effect. And upon clicking your `.btn`, you can [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) on them, so their `width` decreases. Combined with  [css `transition`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) property, it will be animated.

See [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s1dL7m0t/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You could make two `div`'s. I don't think it's possible with one:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  $('#left').animate({
    left: '-100%'
  }, 2000);
  $('#right').animate({
    right: '-100%'
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.container {
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.btn{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin: auto;
  height:30px;
  width: 100px;
}
#left,
#right {
  background-color:royalblue;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <button class="btn">click</button>
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have some fun with pseudo elements ... and no script

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
}
input {
  display: none
}
.btn{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: lightgray;
}
.container::before,
.container::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  transition: width 1s;
}
.container::before {
  left: 0;
}
.container::after {
  right: 0;
}
input:checked + .container::before,
input:checked + .container::after {
  transition: width 1s;
  width: 0;
}
input:checked + .container label {
  transition: opacity 1s;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<input id="inp_btn" type="checkbox">
<div class='container'>
  <label for="inp_btn" class="btn">click</label>
</div>
```